# How can I use "documentation" from the Android app?

Tags: support, android-app, documentation-beta

I see no way to access *documentation* from the Android app.

Comment: Documentation is still in Beta, and it's only been like that for 3 days. The devs are too busy fixing all the problems with it - creating an android app view for it is the least of their worries.

Comment: Alternatively, can't you use a normal web browser on the Android device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. The Documentation feature is only available from the website. There isn't a mobile view either.

You can post a feature request, but I don't think it is of much use at this moment. Let's find out how to use Documentation correctly first.

Comment: No problem, and I didn't add FR on purpose.